# Why aren't ranges' algorithms compatible with std's iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++-concepts, c++20, range-v3

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

int main()
{
    auto coll = std::vector{ 1, 2, 3 };

    ranges::copy(
        coll,
        ranges::ostream_iterator<int>{  std::cout, ", " }
    ); // ok

    ranges::copy(
        coll, 
        std::ostream_iterator<int>{ std::cout, ", " }
    ); // error 
}
```

The issue is shown in the code above. I use [ranges-v3-0.3.7](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).

To me, the generic algorithm `copy` shouldn't care about the destination iterator type as long as it meets the requirements of output iterator.

If so, why aren't ranges' algorithms compatible with std's iterators?

Comment: Mainly because the ranges support is experimental and not yet standard, so the `std::ostream_iterator` is designed without any support of ranges.   The point is demonstrating feasibility of formally introducing such support to a future standard, not locking down a complete specification.Presumably, if ranges is introduced into a future version of the standard, the specification for `ranges::ostream_iterator` will become part of the specification for `std::ostream_iterator`, and `ranges::copy()` will become part of the specification of `std::copy()`, and any incompatibilities will be addressed.

Comment: Peter's answer is not quite accurate. It was intentional that `ranges::copy` requires its output iterator be default constructible. And `ranges::copy` will stay `ranges::copy` (`std::ranges::copy`, to be precise) and not be merged with `std::copy`. See Barry's answer below for the low down.

Comment: @EricNiebler: Does `ranges::copy` need to default-construct its output iterator? (Why?) If not, this seems like a needless incompatibility...

Comment: Did you try with C++20, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/ostream_iterator says that `std::ostream_iterator` is default constructible, which means from the discussions, that it would work.

Comment: @Nemo, I have this feeling that ranges always asks for more than what it needs. I also ask myself, why copy would need default construction of iterator?. Maybe it means that I am not thinking right about the problem. Maybe is a blanket requirement that iterators are proper value types, therefore default-constructible in particular. But it always seem that there is a weaker concept lurking around for any specific algorithm. I once did an  empirical survey of algorithms that syntactically needed default construction: I could find only 2 in STL and they seem to be gratuitous in the implementation

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> To me, the generic algorithm `copy` shouldn't care about the destination iterator type as long as it meets the requirements of output iterator.

This is correct. It's not that `ranges::copy` somehow recognizes `ranges::ostream_iterator` and not `std::ostream_iterator`. It's that Ranges has a refined concept for what an OutputIterator<sup>†</sup> is, such that `ranges::ostream_iterator` does model OutputIterator but `std::ostream_iterator` *does not*.

Specifically, [`ranges::copy()`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/algorithm/copy.hpp#L42) requires [`WeaklyIncrementable<O>`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/utility/iterator_concepts.hpp#L246) which refines [`SemiRegular<O>`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/utility/concepts.hpp#L571) which requires `DefaultConstructible`. [`ranges::ostream_iterator`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/291ffbb9aa88ba5621ebefedd143f6136c55b5da/include/range/v3/utility/iterator.hpp#L580) is default constructible, but [`std::ostream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/ostream_iterator) is not.

Hence the failure.

---

In [P0896](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0896r2.pdf), the range-based `copy()` algorithm does require `WeaklyIncrementable` (and thus `DefaultConstructible`) for its output iterator - but addresses this mismatch by also adding a default constructor to `std::ostream_iterator` (see page 70).

---

As an update to this, [P2325R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2325r3.html) was just adopted retroactively for C++20, which reverts this change. `std::ostream_iterator` will no longer be default constructible and the `weakly_incrementable` concept will no longer require default constructibility (among other changes).

---

<sup>†</sup> Note that the range-v3/Ranges TS/Ranges Proposal concept OutputIterator is separate from the standard library's existing concept of OutputIterator. `std::ostream_iterator` does not model the former but it *does* model the latter - so using `std::copy` with a `std::ostream_iterator` today is perfectly fine. And post-P0896, using `ranges::copy` with a `std::ostream_iterator` will also be fine - because of the proposed changes to `std::ostream_iterator`.

Comment: Yes, much better, and much less scary :)

Comment: Hmm... how come `ranges::ostream_iterator` is default-constructible? Shouldn't it require an ostream?

Comment: @einpoklum It doesn't need to - you can always assign it later.

Comment: @Barry : I thought separating "official" construction from "effective"construction was kind of a no-no these days. Can you even do anything with a `ranges::ostream_iterator {}`?

Comment: @einpoklum No, you can't really.

Comment: @Barry: Weird; I just asked about this in a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56085280/why-is-rangesostream-iterator-default-constructible).

Comment: @einpoklum, `std::ostream_iterator` is default constructible in C++20, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/ostream_iterator.

Comment: @alfC Not as of today.