# New iterator requirements

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++20

I noticed that most if not all containers now require their `::iterator` type to satisfy `LegacySomethingIterator` instead of `SomethingIterator`.

For example, `std::vector<>::iterator` [now requires](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

> `iterator`    [*LegacyRandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)

This seems to be the same for most of the other containers, all requiring their iterators to go from `SomethingIterator` to `LegacySomethingIterator`.

There are also the "new" requirements that took the names of the old requirements, such as [`RandomAccessIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/iterator/RandomAccessIterator), why were these added? It seems to me that the new variants just shadow the legacy variants, no differences.

Why were new ones created in the first place, their requirements look the same to me. Why don't the new ones just replace the old requirements instead of right now having 2 different names for them (e.g. `RandomAccessIterator` and `LegacyRandomAccessIterator`)?

Comment: Note that the old and new iterator requirements do have some differences: [Why aren't ranges' algorithms compatible with std's iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52435630/why-arent-ranges-algorithms-compatible-with-stds-iterators)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

These are not new things, hence the term "legacy". This is simply how the cppreference site chooses to reconcile the fact that C++20 will have two different things that are both "concepts" called "RandomAccessIterator" (well, until C++20 decided to rename their version `random_access_iterator`).

Pre-C++20, a "concept" was just a set of requirements in the standard that represented the behavior expected of certain template parameters. In C++20, with concepts becoming an actual language feature, that needed to shift. The problem is that the Ranges `concept` of "`RandomAccessIterator`" is *not the same* as the old-style "concept" of "RandomAccessIterator".

Since C++ considers them both to be "concepts" (though only the newer one is a `concept` in the language sense), they would both have the same page name on the Wiki. And MediaWiki doesn't really allow that.

So the maintainers of the site settled on using "Legacy" to differentiate them. Note that the actual *standard* doesn't use this "Legacy" prefix.

Note that the C++20 standard does have a prefix for the older concepts: "Cpp17". So the old concept would be "Cpp17RandomAccessIterator". That was not deemed appropriate for Cppreference for obvious reasons.

Comment: Haha that's funny. I actually edited out that part. My initial post had another question asking if the standard uses the term *LegacyIterator* but then I thought to myself it has to be because cppreference is always very standard compliant. Guess not in this case, thanks :)

Comment: @SombreroChicken The standard uses "Cpp17" as the prefix instead, but I don't want to document a C++98 component as requiring a Cpp17Thingamabob.