# Can you help me identify which iterator is being used here?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Can you help me identify which iterator is being used here? (Trivial, input, output)

```
        int maxIndx = -1;
        int maxSize = -1;
        for (map<int, set<string> >::iterator itr = partitions.begin(); itr != partitions.end(); ++itr) {
            int size = (*itr).second.size();
            if (size > maxSize) {
                maxSize = size;
                maxIndx = (*itr).first;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Side note: I recommend using `iter->second.size()` and `iter->first` rather than the dereference and dot notation. It's easier to read.

Comment: With problems like this, a good way to solution is to read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is documented as having an `iterator` typedef that is a LegacyBidirectionalIterator.

(cppreference is not official, but it's free, easy, and pretty darn accurate)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are these iterators 'Legacy'?

Comment: You probably have a question worthy of a question, @PaulSanders. In my world the legacy code is usually the code that worked.

Comment: @PaulSanders [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970846/5522303) seems to answer that question

Comment: @Kevin Sure does, thank you.