# Why is the c++ filesystem directory_iterator a LegacyIterator?

Tags: c++, templates, fold-expression

According to the docs here this iterator is a LegacyInputIterator, which is a LegacyIterator. Now, according to my understanding of the meaning of 'legacy', it means this:

> In computing, a legacy system is an old method, technology, computer
> system, or application program, "of, relating to, or being a previous
> or outdated computer system,"[1] yet still in use. - Wikipedia
>
> 5. of or pertaining to old or outdated computer hardware, software, or data that, while still functional, does not work well with up-to-date
>    systems. - Dictionary

So in my code to iterator through some folders I do this:

std::filesystem::directory_iterator iter{ "c:/folder" };

```
while (iter != std::filesystem::directory_iterator{})
{
    // Do something with the file
    ++iter;
}
```

I'm just wondering if there's a better or newer way of doing this, as I have suspicions over the use of the term legacy for the iterators I'm using.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53970756/new-iterator-requirements

Answer (score 4):

The LegacyIterator is a named-requirement from the C++ standard. The "Legacy" part was added in C++20, to differentiate Concepts names from unchecked, named-requirements imposed by the previous standards on certain types.

It is just an old name from the standard for a set of requirements, that certain types have. You can use it without worry.

Comment: Maybe if we called them "classic" iterators, that would make them sound cool.