# Iterator concepts are weaker than the corresponding named requirements, which ones apply to the non-range standard algorithms?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

In C++20 we got concepts for iterator categories, e.g. [`std::forward_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/forward_iterator) corresponds to named requirement [*ForwardIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator).

They are not equivalent. In some (but not all) regards, the concepts are weaker:

- [(1)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/forward_iterator) *"Unlike the [ForwardIterator or stricter] requirements, the [corresponding] concept does not require dereference to return an lvalue."*
- [(2)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_iterator)
  *"Unlike the [InputIterator] requirements, the `input_iterator` concept does not require `equality_comparable`, since input iterators are typically compared with sentinels."*
- ...

The new `std::ranges` algorithms seem to use the concepts to check iterator requirements.

But what about the other standard algorithms? (that existed pre-C++20)

Do they still use the same iterator requirements in C++20 as they were pre-C++20, or did the requirements for them get relaxed to match the concepts?

Comment: I wanted to vote to reopen my question, but I was able to single-handedly reopen it. :/

Comment: Not sure if [Difference between Ranges algorithms and std algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63867796/2752075) is the right dupe. It doesn't explicitly say if the requirements for the old algorithms were relaxed or left as is.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking what the algorithm requirements *are*? The phrasing of "I should use" is confusing - should use in what sense?

Comment: @Barry Edited, it should be better now. I'm asking if the old standard algorithms (non-`std::ranges` ones) still use the old (stricter) iterator requirements, or if the requirements for them were relaxed to match the concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do they still use the same iterator requirements in C++20 as they were pre-C++20, or did the requirements for them get relaxed to match the concepts?

The existing `std::` algorithms still use the named requirements. For instance, [[alg.find]](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.find) has both:

```cpp
template<class InputIterator, class T>
  constexpr InputIterator find(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                               const T& value);
```

and

```cpp
template<input_­iterator I, sentinel_­for<I> S, class T, class Proj = identity>
  requires indirect_­binary_­predicate<ranges::equal_to, projected<I, Proj>, const T*>
  constexpr I ranges::find(I first, S last, const T& value, Proj proj = {});
template<input_­range R, class T, class Proj = identity>
  requires indirect_­binary_­predicate<ranges::equal_to, projected<iterator_t<R>, Proj>, const T*>
  constexpr borrowed_iterator_t<R>
    ranges::find(R&& r, const T& value, Proj proj = {});
```

The same is true for all the algorithms.

---

Note that there is a proposal to change this: [Ranges views as inputs to non-Ranges algorithms](https://wg21.link/p2408). That paper would change the named requirements to become in line with the `concept`s (note that it would *not* change the `std::` algorithms to accept sentinels).